# Accessing list item in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a list, rate_text [`'', 'Disappointed', 'Not Promissing', 'OK', 'Good', 'Awesome']` in the template rendered from the view. I can access any of the item of that using `{{rate_text.index}}` like the following:

```
{% for review in reviews %}
<div class="panel panel-info" style='border-color:#ffffff;'>
    <div class="panel-heading" >
        <h3 class="panel-title lead">{{review.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       <p class='text-center'>{{review.review}}</p>
       <h5 class='text-right'>-{{review.username}} ( {{review.email}} ) </h5>
       <h5 class='text-right'>Rating : {{rate_text.4}}</h5>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
{% endfor %}
```

But, in stead of using index in `{{rate_text.index}}` I would like to use `{{review.rating}}` as index. Is there any way that this can be done ??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#choices) attribute for the `rating` field:

```
RATING_CHOICES = list(enumerate(['', 'Disappointed', 'Not Promissing',
                                 'OK', 'Good', 'Awesome']))

class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    rating = models.IntegerField(..., choices=RATING_CHOICES)
```

And then use it in the template:

```
{{ review.get_index_display }}
```

The other option is to use [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
@register.filter
def get_by_index(lst, idx):
    return lst[idx]
```

Template will look like this:

```
{{ rate_text|get_by_index:review.rating }}
```